# Could a parallel redundancy protocol "PRP" be implemented over Debian?

Tags: linux, network-protocols, redundancy

I want to connect a PC to an existing PRP topology, this PC have two Ethernet ports.
I have been reading up a lot about PRP protocol, but i don't know if i can setup the PRP protocol over a linux system withot use additional hardware, or if it only depends on wheter the network card supports the protocol.

I'm using Debian to develop.

Answer (score 1):

There is a driver for PRP from TI. I haven't tested it myself but it seems to be in the mainline kernel now.

If your kernel doesn't have PRP support, you need to enable HSR in the kernel. HSR and PRP are similar and share the same code.

Here is a good presentation from TI that shows how to create a PRP link: [HSR and PRP Redundancy on RT Linux, Part 4: Linux Commands](https://training.ti.com/sites/default/files/docs/HSR-PRP-Redundancy-RT-Linux-P4.pdf)

Comment: The `hsr.ko` module is available in mainline kernel, but it seems that iproute2 is compiled without PRP support

Comment: The link in the answer appears to lead to a generic page. [Here](https://www.ti.com/video/5399385055001) is an updated link to the video (or just the [presentation](https://www.ti.com/content/dam/videos/external-videos/2/3816841626001/5399385055001.mp4/subassets/HSR-PRP-Redundancy-RT-Linux-P4.pdf))